# spring saml signature verification and decryption order for assertion

Tags: spring-saml

Currently spring saml seems to check signature first before decrypting the assertion while idp being used is signing the assertion first resulting in spring saml failing to verify signature. Is there a way order of signature verification and decryption can be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Boneh in https://class.coursera.org/crypto-preview/wiki/LectureSlidesPublicCourse does not recommend such a switching. It's more vulnerable.